# Integrating the Facebook Login into an iOS iPad application

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, authentication

*Sorry if this question is framed incorrectly.*

I am working on an iPad application that needs to leverage the Facebook login feature.  The application is supposed to allow a user to login to his Facebook account when the application first starts up. My questions are:

1. What part of the Facebook API will I need to use just to be able to login to facebook? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/
2. How can I keep track of the use's session?
3. What type of permissions will I need to ask the user a poll question (ie a survey)?

**For anyone facing similar problems I'll be updating this question with relevant links.**

> [iOS Facebook library login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086149/ios-facebook-library-login)
>
> [Facebook iOS SDK: Login to Facebook without always ask for permissions for the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232063/facebook-ios-sdk-login-to-facebook-without-always-ask-for-permissions-for-the-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has detailed instructions on authentication and sessions in their API docs.  See here for a tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

The access token and expiration is stored in the user defaults and is saved once the user is authenticated by Facebook

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```